# My C code doesnt work

Tags: c, pointers

Im trying to write a program that accepts a string from users and then converts each character to its corresponding 8-bit binary code and store it in a char array(or char array of pointer type). I have the following code but it giving me error(segmentation).

**UPDATE**
I have initialized pointer p as many of you pointer out thanks!
But still I'm getting strange outputs.

Please help:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int xstrlen (char *s) //for later use
{
int length = 0 ;
while ( *s != '\0' )
{
length++ ;
s++ ;
}
return ( length ) ;
}

char* showbits(int n)
{
int i, k, andmask ;

char* p=(char *)malloc(9);
for ( i = 7 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
{
    andmask = 1 << i ;
    k = n & andmask ;

    if(k==0)
    {
       strcat(p,"0");
    }

    else
    {
       strcat(p,"1");
    }
}
//*p='\0'; Have removed this line
return p;
}


void msg2bits(char *msg)
{

    char* bits;
 //   char *bits=(char*)malloc(9);
    int x;
    int i=0;


   while(*msg!='\0')
   {
       x=(int)msg[i];
      // char *bits=(char*)malloc(9);
       bits=showbits(x);

       puts(bits);
       msg++;
       i++;
      // free(bits);
    }
}


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char *msg="ABCD";

    msg2bits(msg);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I have made showbits and msg2bits as two seperate functions as you might be thinking why not combine them beacuse I will do further processing the function msg2bits once im throught this problem.

Thanks in advance people!

P.S I cannot upload image of the output because of my reputation *sigh

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? Run it with GDB and trace where the segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: In showbits p is just a dangling pointer - you need to allocate some memory for the string that you are going to return.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Not only have you not initialized `p` in `showbits()`, but you try to return it for use in the calling function.  You definitely need to make sure `p` is initialized, but simply returning a pointer to a local variable in the function is going to cause trouble too.  You should probably pass a pointer into the function that points to enough space for it to use.  Make sure the string is null terminated too (it isn't yet).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for your suggestion. I've made the changes as you mentioned above but I'm getting strange output. Please help again. im new to pointers. :)

Comment: Also, don't cast the outcome of a malloc and do give it the size of the type. I know in this case char is always 1, just that it looks very ugly. 
`char* p = malloc(9 * sizeof(char));`

Comment: After you malloc p you need to initialise the first character to `'\0'` in order for strcat to work correctly.

Comment: @PaulR: Thank You so much Paul... That did the trick!!!! Yippie so happy :-)

Comment: `x=(int)msg[i];` change to `x=*msg;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this snippet :

```
 while(*msg!='\0')
       {
           x=(int)msg[i];
          // char *bits=(char*)malloc(9);
           bits=showbits(x);

           puts(bits);
           msg++;
           i++;
          // free(bits);
        }
```

For example msg = "1234"

```
i = 0 & msg = "1234" :
x = 1
i++; msg++ ==> i=1 & msg = "234" :
x = 3
.
.
.
```

you are stepping over some of your msg characters by incrementing  two times inside the same loop